# What does "a price drift" mean exactly?

Tags: meaning

I have found several times the expression "a price drift" or "price drifts" refering to stock price movements (drift(s) being used as a noun and not a verb).

I have looked up dictionaries and there are many possible definitions of drift as a noun, so I am not sure what the expression implies. Does it merely mean "a price change"? Or does it convey other subtleties such as randomness, lack of direction, lack of cause, gradualness or slowness in the movement (these being some of the definitions...)? If the latter is the case, which one of the many possible subtleties does it convey?

Thanks.

Comment: It's the second definition [here](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/drift_2)

Comment: A price drift is when the price of something drifts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It implies gradual and usually directionless change without a direct or obvious cause. It is possible to supply a direction "Prices have drifted upwards" means that they have gradually increased (perhaps with some short periods of decrease) without a specific cause.

Comment: Well, to nitpick, presumably there is SOME cause. But in this case, the cause is difficult to pin down. It SEEMS random and aimless.

Comment: I don't see why that is a "nitpick" since I've already made exactly the point in the answer  "without a **direct or obvious** cause",  "without a **specific** cause."

Comment: How about when the media says **The bad news caused a downwards price drift**? There is a **cause** and a **direction**, which goes against the definition. This is what I don't get about the usage of this word.

Comment: That would be bad writing, of which there is plenty. But sure,  if you provide a specific cause, as in that example, the only remaining elements of the sense of "drift" are that it  is gradual.  The media would be using "drift" to contrast with "drop" or "crash".